# How to disable emoji from WordPress 4.2

Tags: php, wordpress, emoji

Is there any way to disable emoji's from WordPress 4.2 without plugin? I am using Genesis Framework for my site please help.

Comment: You can do it by editing your theme's functions.php file. This is the exact code you need to add, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185577/disable-emojicons-introduced-with-wp-4-2

Comment: emojis or 'smileys'?

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1.)** *hook into* `init`

```
function disable_wp_emojicons() {

  // all actions related to emojis
  remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
  remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
  remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
  remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
  remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );

  // filter to remove TinyMCE emojis
  add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_emojicons' );
```

**Step 2.)** *filter function*

```
function disable_emojicons_tinymce( $plugins ) {
  if ( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
    return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
  } else {
    return array();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can add above code or use  below code

```
    // REMOVE WP EMOJI
remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');

remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

Both will help you to remove emoji from your site. to know more visit http://www.notesonclick.com/blog/remove-wordpress-emoji-code/

Answer (score 1):

Just put the following code into function.php file :

```
function disable_wp_emojicons() {

  remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
  remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
  remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
  remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
  remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );

  // filter to remove TinyMCE emojis

  add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_emojicons' );

// Disable TinyMCE emojicons

function disable_emojicons_tinymce( $plugins ) {
  if ( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
    return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
  } else {
    return array();
  }
}

//Remove DNS Prefetch

add_filter( 'emoji_svg_url', '__return_false' );;
```

I was inspired from this post : http://www.codecanal.com/how-to-disable-emoji-support-in-wordpress-4-2-without-a-plugin/